# In iPhone, CSS not working in Email Template

Tags: html, css

Here is my email template code. That is not working on the iPhone.In iPhone, the mail template is disturbing with the design. In android mobile looks fine. I had searched for lots of things about my problem. but, I could not find any solution. Your help will appreciate. can anyone help me?

Html

```
    <body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;position: relative;min-height: 100vh;background-color: #e7e4ff;">
    <div class="mail_temp_section">
        <div class="mail_temp_card">
            <h2>Welcome to the team!</h2>
            <div class="input_field">
                <label style="padding: 1.5625VW;">License
                    <span>8999-879878-45131-3213</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <p>Activate your account in our <a href="#" style="border-bottom: 0.104vw solid #836dfa;">dashboard</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="twitter_link"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CnNLZmj/twitter.png" alt="twitter" style="vertical-align: sub;
                margin-right: 0.2vw; height: 1.25VW; width: 1.25VW;"> Feel free to reach out via Facebook</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Arial Black';
}
.mail_temp_section {
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mail_temp_card {
    background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/YZgs2vS/mail-bg.png);
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    width: 45.6vw;
    padding: 6vw;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 1.6vw;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: bottom center;
}

.mail_temp_card h2 {
    color: #775cff;
    font-size: 2vw;
    padding-bottom: 2vw;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.input_field {
    background-color: #e3e3f2;
    padding: 1.4vw;
    border-radius: 1.6vw;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 30px -5px rgba(204, 204, 236, 0.65);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 30px -5px rgba(204, 204, 236, 0.65);
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 30px -5px rgba(204, 204, 236, 0.65);
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

.input_field label {
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: #2e3246;
    padding: 30px;
}

.input_field span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0.3vw 1vw;
    color: #2e3246;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    margin-top: 0.5vw;
    cursor: text;
}

.mail_temp_card p {
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    padding-top: 4.5vw;
    color: #2e3246;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}

.mail_temp_card p a {
    color: #836dfa;
    border-bottom: 0.104vw solid #836dfa;
}

.mail_temp_card>a.twitter_link {
    color: #2e3246;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    margin-top: 0.7vw;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}

a.twitter_link {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a.twitter_link img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Suggestion, Please use table structure for email template it could be good prectice. :)

Comment: use tables for html mails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to send email template then use a table but designing email template by yourself will not guarantee will work the same in all email client,

> Try to get some email boilerplate of email template and tweak it to your needs

below are some link to get email boilerplate

https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template

https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate/blob/master/email.html

https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/email-templates